# Data source name is not appearing in System DSN for MS access ODBC connection

Tags: oracle11g, ms-access-2016

Can anyone help me with this?

I have to connect the oracle data source in MS access which has already connected with some HANA server. But now i want to connect it to oracle.

I have done the odbc connection in System DSN from Administrator tools. Connection successful. But, still i cannot see that DSN in System DSN.

Tried the following steps but still not working
1. Modified default value as "value not set" in regedit.
2. created System DSN through this "C:\windows\SysWOW64"

TIA

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot see the System DSN you created in the Control Panel, or that you cannot see it when you open MS Access and try to connect to external data?

Comment: i cannot see the DSN which i created in System DSN in the control panel.

Comment: Two follow-up questions: After successfully testing the connection, are you sure that you OK'd out of the dialog, or did you just close it?  Also, when you return to the control panel to look for the System DSN, are you logged in as an administrator?

Comment: For first question: my answer is yes i clicked ok and am closing the dialog.

Comment: For second question: I am not logged in as an admin